# How to define tickColor property of annotation at dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am using Dygraph and I am setting annotations over the line chart. My problem is that I defined tickColor property for the annotation, but the annotation take the color of the trend and no the color that I am defining.

My code:

```
scoreChart = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("scorechart"),
  ad,
  {
     colors: ['blue'],
     height: 200,
    });

scoreChart.ready(function() {
  scoreChart.setAnnotations([{
      series: "Score",
      x: '2016/04/25 07:25:14',
      shortText: 'g120_wi',
      tickHeight: 280,
      tickColor: "red",
      attachAtBottom: true,
      tickWidth: 2
   }]);
});
```

Result: (I hope annotation line in red as I set in tickColor property. But I want trend in blue)

[image]

Comment: Was using the version 1.1.1 of Dygraph. I change to version 2.0 and tickColor work fine